# Ansible Playbook lineinfile insertafter is placed at end of file rather than designated destination

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible

I have a task within my playbook where I want to add a new line and then place it after a certain line but after I run it, it adds to the bottom of the file rather than the destination I would like it to be. Any chance to why this keeps being placed at the end of my file? There are a total of 41 lines in the sshd_confiq file.

```
    - name: Add GSSAPIKexAlgorithms in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        line: 'GSSAPIKexAlgorithms=gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-'
        insertafter: '17'
        state: present
        create: true
      become: true
      become_method: sudo
```

Results

```
Protocol 2
ListenAddress 127.0.0.1
ListenAddress 10.224.122.141
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
LogLevel VERBOSE
PermitRootLogin no
MaxAuthTries 3
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
HostbasedAuthentication no
IgnoreRhosts yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes
Ciphers=aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
MACs=hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
KexAlgorithms=curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
HostKeyAlgorithms=ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFIcatION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
X11Forwarding no
AllowTCPForwarding yes
AllowAgentForwarding yes
ClientAliveCountMax 0
ClientAliveInterval 900
Banner /etc/issue
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
DenyGroups service

Match User AWS_GDIT_Nessus,AWS_GDIT_Retina,AWS_IP360,nessus_service
    PasswordAuthentication yes
Match Group ansible
    PasswordAuthentication no
    GSSAPIAuthentication no
    KerberosAuthentication no
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
GSSAPIKexAlgorithms=gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-
sh-4.4$
```

Emros Correction:

```
    - name: Add GSSAPIKexAlgorithms in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        line: 'GSSAPIKexAlgorithms=gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-'
        insertafter: '^.*MACs=hmac-sha2-256'
        state: present
        create: true
      become: true
      become_method: sudo
```

Full Ansible Playbook

```
---
- name: MAC SSH Vulnerability FIX
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Backing up /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      shell: cp -prf /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.10-19-23
      become: true
      become_method: sudo

    - name: Uncomment the CRYPTO_POLICY setting in /etc/sysconfig/sshd file
      replace:
        path: /etc/sysconfig/sshd
        regexp: '# CRYPTO_POLICY='
        replace: 'CRYPTO_POLICY='
      become: true
      become_method: sudo

    - name: Updating ciphers directive in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        regexp: '^Ciphers'
        line: 'Ciphers=aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr'
      become: true
      become_method: sudo

    - name: Updating MACs directive in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        regexp: '^Macs'
        line: 'MACs=hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512'
      become: true
      become_method: sudo

    - name: Add GSSAPIKexAlgorithms in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        line: 'GSSAPIKexAlgorithms=gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-'
        insertafter: '^.*MACs=hmac-sha2-256'
        state: present
        create: true
      become: true
      become_method: sudo

    - name: Updating KexAlgorithms in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        regexp: '^KexAlgorithms'
        line: 'KexAlgorithms=curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'
      become: true
      become_method: sudo

    - name: Updating HostKeyAlgorithms in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        line: 'HostKeyAlgorithms=ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com'
        insertafter: '18'
      become: true
      become_method: sudo

    - name: Restarting sshd service
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      ansible.builtin.service: 
        name: sshd 
        state: restarted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand,
You seem to want to insert a line after '17', but it's not possible with the lineinfile module to insert based on a line number.
Line 17 corresponds to 'PasswordAuthentication yes,' so I suggest you change your code to the following:

```
- name: "Add GSSAPIKexAlgorithms in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file"
  lineinfile:
    path: "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
    line: 'GSSAPIKexAlgorithms=gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-'
    insertafter: '^PasswordAuthentication yes'
    state: present
  become: yes
```

In this example, the GSSAPIKexAlgorithms line will be added after the line containing 'PasswordAuthentication yes,' which is line 17 in the provided file.

You can use template module if you dont want to use line in file module.

Comment: -Emros I would like for it to go after the "Macs=" line

Comment: @01Tech add insertafter: '^.*MACs=hmac-sha2-256' 
you have some documentation here  --> https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html

Comment: -Emros see above. Is that correct?

Comment: @01Tech  Yep ive done it on somes playbooks , just replace this line -->

    insertafter: '^.*MACs=hmac-sha2-256'

Comment: -Emros Looks like it worked! That's odd as when I first tried this I had it like this before I used the line number method and it was still going to the bottom of the file:

 insertafter: '^.*MACs='

Comment: No problem ! Sometime its a little bit weird :) You can validate my answer if you want. Contact me if you have another question about ansible or another topic stackoverflow

Comment: -Emros Thank you so much for the explanation! Is there a way to message you on here or something directly your saying?

Comment: @01Tech on stack i dont think ... but i have a email --> florian@zesaas.com you can adress me a mail with link of your ticket overflow or question :D

Comment: I just sent you an email @Emros -Emros